# How did the two F-35 planes get from Fort Worth to Williamtown?

Tags: military, range, f-35, australia

I am curious as to how the the F-35s that recently arrived in Williamtown, Australia did arrive there.

Were they transported at any point, or were they flown the entire way?

How many stops did they make?

Did Australian pilots land them in Australia? If so did Australian pilots take off in them from Fort Worth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The two aircraft had been delivered to the RAAF at Luke in September and October and delivered to Williamtown via Hickam Air Force Base in Hawaii and RAAF Base Amberley, south-east of Brisbane.

From [Defense News](https://www.defensenews.com/global/asia-pacific/2018/12/10/f-35-fighters-arrive-on-australian-soil/).

Comment: So did they have to do two mid air refuelling sessions from Fort Worth to Hickam Air Force base?

Comment: There is an art and science to scheduling refueling on long overwater legs.  The tanker stays with you and the goal is to keep you topped off so that you can make the nearest divert field.  They will never let you get too low.  Rather than one or two long drinks you will get multiple sips to stay topped off.  Hard to say exactly how many though.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I wonder if the fuel was complimentary or the US invoiced them.

Comment: My guess is US already include fuel in the bill.

Answer (score 4):

When Australia received two F-35's in February of last year they were flown by Royal Australian Air Force pilots according to [This article](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-02-27/joint-strike-fighters-f35-land-in-australia/8308498). So I would imagine they did the same for the most recent delivery. Pilots were flown to Fort Worth and they took command of the fighters and flew them back to Australia.

According to [9news](https://www.9news.com.au/2018/12/02/04/39/royal-australian-air-force-raaf-f35-fighter-jet-plane-williamton-newcastle) "The two F35s will spend several days making a relatively slow trip to Australia touching down in Hawaii and Guam as well as air to air refueling."